# PHP CURL POST in foreach loop - returns 403

Tags: php, curl, post, foreach

im having some trouble with curl.
I have an foreachloop where i make an simple postrequest with curl at the end.
But i always get an 403 back.

But when i try the same code with an defined array and without a foreach its working.

I hope someone has an idea for that.

**Test Array**

```
    $test = array (
        'name' => 'Peter Apimann',
        'email' => 'a@a.de',
        'website' => 'www.a.de',
        'phonenumber' => '123456789',
        'company' => 'Apimann Gmbh',
        'address' => 'Straße 1',
        'city' => 'Neu-Isengard',
        'zip' => '12345',
        'state' => 'Mordor',
        'description' => 'We are a fictional Company',
        'isCompetitor'  => false,
        'source' => '11',
        'status' => '16',
'custom_fields[leads][11]' => "<a target='_blank' href='https://google.de'>visit link</a>"
    );
    
    //var_dump($test);
    
    $url = "https://example.com/api/endpoint";
    $requestHeader[] = "authtoken: 123456789";
    
    
    $fields_string = http_build_query($test);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$requestHeader);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    
    curl_close($ch);
```

**In my foreach Loop**

```
<?php

foreach( $postdata AS $item ) {

...

        $url = "https://example.com/api/endpoint";
        $requestHeader[] = "authtoken: 123456789";
        
        
        $fields_string = http_build_query($item);
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$requestHeader);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
                  
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result;
        
        curl_close($ch);   
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you are being rate limited by the API?

Comment: no, there is no limit. i have also tried with a "sleep(10);" between the post, but i got always an 403. When i put the data in an array like my testarray its workin without any problems.

Comment: what does item contain in the postdata loop (can you post a vardump)? And it is a public api? Then we can test it.

Comment: Seems like you need to find out if the content in `$item` is the same as your `$test` array. Looks like thats the only difference in your top and bottom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it.
i´m sure it´s not the best solution but it works. :)

**First i put each item into an own array instead of do the post directly.**

```
foreach( $postdata AS $item ) {
...
$itemsToSend[] = $item;
}
```

**Then i created a simple function**

```
function postTheItems ($postarray) {
$url = "https://example.com/api/endpoint";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$requestHeader= array(
"authtoken: 123456789",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeader);

$postarray= http_build_query($postarray);

$data = <<<DATA
$postarray
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
```

**Finally i created another foreach and call the function**

```
foreach ( $final_post_data AS $item ) {
    postTheItems ($itemsToSend);
}
```